# MainActivity com Login

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de se utilizar uma aplicação com Login (em relação às activities).

Estou utilizando a MainActivity com um Navigation Drawer, e ao abrir o aplicativo ele verifica se há credenciais num banco sqlite3 (se foi feito o login) e então, caso seja necessário fazer o login, executa outra Activity do Login deixando a primeira em espera.

Ao logar, ele finaliza com `finish()` a acitvity do Login e volta pra Main.  Na activity do Login no método `onBackPressioned()` eu fiz com que todas as activities fossem finalizadas e o programa saísse.

Por fim, só falta eu entender como atualizar os dados da MainActivity após fazer o Login (ou seja, um textfield da MainActivity que deve ter seu valor alterado, por ex).

Não sei se é a melhor forma, tentei procurar na internet mas não encontrei tantos exemplos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em vez de lançar a *activity* Login com `startActivity()` faça-o com `startActivityForResult()`

```
//Constante para identificar o resultado
static final int TEXT_RESULT = 1;
startActivityForResult(oSeuIntent, TEXT_RESULT);
```

Na *Activity* Login na altura de fazer `finish()`

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",stringQueQuerPassar);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Na *Activity* que lança Login

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == TEXT_RESULT) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //Receba a string que vem de Login
            String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi. Eu estava achando que era na LoginActivity que eu deveria atualizar os textFields mas no método onActivityResult eu posso fazer isto, certo?

Comment: Se os textFields são da MainActivity sim.